# django 1.5: not being able to get the values of variable in view

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am new to django. I have django 1.5. I want to take two variables from one template to some other template. but i am not receiving the value instead just nothing received.

Code of the Template from which i want to send variable as a part of url is:

```
<div class="tags">
                  {% for tags1 in document.tags.all %}
                    {% if tags1.name|length > 0 %}
                    {% with tags1.name as tagts %}{% endwith %}
                    <a href="{% url 'tag_related_document' user tagts %}">{{ tags1.name }}</a>
                    {% endif %}
                  {% endfor %}
                  </div>
```

Code of the URL where i am calling Second View is:

```
url(r'^tag_related/(?P<username>[-\w\.@]+)/(?P<tagts>)/$',
       tag_related_document,
       {'template_name': 'document/tag_related_document.html'},
       name = 'tag_related_document'
    ),
```

Code of the View tag_related_document is:

```
def tag_related_document(request, username, tagts, template_name , page_template="userprofile/entry_index_page.html"):
    """
   documents  Related to tag    """
    try:
        notifications = request.user.notifications.all()[:100]
    except AttributeError:
        notifications = ""

    user = get_object_or_404(User, username = username)

    try:
        user_profile = user.get_profile()
    except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
        messages.error(request, "Profile does not exist.")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('homepage'))

    documents = Document.objects.filter( Q(tags__in = user_profile.tags.all()) , date_deleted = None).order_by("-date_added")
    if not documents:
        documents = Document.objects.filter( date_deleted = None).order_by("?")
    related_doc_widget = Document.objects.filter( Q(tags__in = user_profile.tags.all()) , date_deleted = None).order_by('?')
    if not related_doc_widget:
        related_doc_widget = Document.objects.filter( date_deleted = None).order_by("?")

    followers_widget = Felloz.objects.get_followers(user = user_profile.user)
    followings_widget = Felloz.objects.get_followings(user = user_profile.user)
#    recommendations_widget = UserProfile.objects.filter(Q(~Q(user__in = followings_widget) or ~Q(user = request.user) ) ).order_by('?')

    recommendations_widget = UserProfile.objects.filter( tags__in = user_profile.tags.all() ).distinct().exclude(user__in = followings_widget).exclude( user = user )
    if not recommendations_widget:
        recommendations_widget = UserProfile.objects.filter(~Q( user__in = followings_widget ) ).exclude( user = user ).order_by('?')

    ideas_widget = Idea.objects.filter(user = user).order_by('?')
    for idea in ideas_widget:
            is_substring = "<a" in idea.idea_html
            if(is_substring is False):
                idea.idea_html = truncate_chars(idea.idea_html,50)
            else:
                idea.idea_html = htmltruncate.truncate(idea.idea_html,50,ellipsis='')   

    no_of_documents = len( Document.objects.filter(author = user) )
    no_of_ideas = len(Idea.objects.filter(user=user))
    try:
        slug_status = SlugStatus.objects.get(user=user)
    except SlugStatus.DoesNotExist:
        slug_status = ''

    context = {
        'slug_status':slug_status,
        'documents': documents, 
        'page_template': page_template,
        'followers_widget': followers_widget,
        'followings_widget': followings_widget,
        'related_doc_widget': related_doc_widget,
        'user': user,
        'site': Site.objects.get_current(),
        'profile':user_profile,
        'recommendations_widget': recommendations_widget,
        'no_of_documents':no_of_documents,
        'no_of_ideas': no_of_ideas,
        'notifications': notifications,
        'notifications_unread': request.user.notifications.unread(),
        'idea_widget': ideas_widget,
        'tagts':tagts,
    }
    print '=============i m here==================='
    print tagts
    print '=============i m here==================='
#related_doc_widget = Document.objects.filter(~Q(author = user) and ~Q(tags__in = UserProfile.tags.all())).order_by('?')
#recommendations_widget = UserProfile.objects.filter(~Q(user__in = followings_widget) and ~Q(user = user)).order_by('?')

#documents_newsfeed = Document.objects.filter(Q(author = user) | Q(author__in = followings_widget), date_deleted = None).order_by("-date_added")

    if request.is_ajax():
        template_name = page_template
    return render_to_response(template_name, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    return render_to_response(template_name, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The code of the Second Template where i want to show that variable is:

```
{% if profile.user == request.user %}
            <h2 class="mainHeading"> Documents Related To: {{tagts}} </h2>
        {% else %}
            <h2 class="mainHeading"> Documents Related To: {{tagts}}</h2>
            {% endif %}
```

But i am getting here nothing.... Please help thanks in advance....

Comment: What happens when you print `tagts` in the view?

Comment: nothing is shown, perhaps a null value....

Answer (score 0):

You are closing `{% with %}` before `{% url %}` so url is being based on empty value, i think it's the reason.

And please, in future avoid posting large pieces of irrelevant code. Shrink it down to minimal amount which is needed to reproduce error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...I did this only just because someone felt no confusion in understanding the problem. I shall avoid in future to post large pieces of code. :-)

Dear i have did but i am having another error with this change.
"NoReverseMatch at /document/f50bc24217/documents-list/
Reverse for 'tag_related_document' with arguments '(<User: f50bc24217>, u' tage')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found."

Comment: Because you should use something like `user.username` to build URL

Comment: Guys thanks for your help, i have resolved my issue myself. it was just the problem of regular expression in the url. it was not allowing blank spaces while they were there in the data to pass.

Answer (score 0):

Should be like this unless the code doesn't resemble the one you posted.

```
{% for tags1 in document.tags.all %}
      {% if tags1.name|length > 0 %}
        {% with tags1.name as tagts %}
         <a href="{% url 'tag_related_document' user tagts %}">{{ tags1.name }}</a>
        {% endwith %}
      {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```